# Gitlab AutoDeploy

Tags: apache, gitlab, githooks

Here is my Situation, I have a webserver and a gitlab server for my repositories, I am trying to auto update my site once I push to my remote branch, I am able to autoupdate if I push directly from my laptop to the web server, but I want to push to my gitlab server and I want my gitlab server to update my website that is located in another server.

On my server I have a post-receive hook with the following content

## !/bin/sh

git --work-tree=/var/www/html/site --git-dir=/var/repo/site checkout -f

that will work If i push from my laptop to the webserver. not from my gitlab I guess that I need a hook on my gitlab server bit I cannot find anything online.

Answer (score 1):

We are using gitlab-ci in such cases.
You can setup gitlab-ci inside your gitlab instance.
gitlab-ci will trigger a script when you push to gitlab-server.
In the script you can update the web server content.

There is another way to update the web server it's use the gitlab web hooks.
On your web server you should create a url for call a git command for the web server content update. Then open your gitlab project, in Settings/Web hooks create new hook that points to the url created above. When you push into gitlab it triggers the hook and your web site will be updated.

I think the second way will be more applicable for your case.

Answer (score 0):

gitlab-ci is one of the solutions.

it's very simple,

- Create gitlab runner.
- Add a .gitlab-ci.yml file to the root directory of your repository.